# Error ggplot: Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a plot but I want to have a seperate boxplot for each x number. So, now it is one big boxplot, but I want to have boxplots for each value between 1 and 16.

```
ggplot(listings, mapping = aes(x = accommodates, y = price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  ylim(0, 500) +
  ggtitle("Boxplot of the price vs accommodation space") +
  xlab("Accommodation space") + ylab("Price ($)")
```

[image]

Hopefully you can help me!

Comment: Have you tried facet_grid()?

Comment: No, but I do not want 16 different plots, I want 16 boxplots in 1 plot/graph

Comment: use `aes(x=as.factor(accommodates), y=price)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can either get separate boxes by making `x` a discrete variable (e.g. using `factor(x)` as suggested in the comments), or by providing grouping on a continuous variable. In your case you'd be better to leave `x` as a continuous variable so you can add the `geom_smooth()`. Compare these three examples below. I think you want to use the third.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# x is continuous with no grouping generating a single box
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
#> Warning: Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
# x is discrete so geom_smooth is meaningless
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = disp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
# x is continuous to enable geom_smooth but grouping is applied to give boxes
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>